# Symfony2 can a web application be like a computer client?

Tags: symfony

I'm developping an application that I should give to a person only to test its functionality, and I don't want him to have the code.
I also do not want to host the application and give him a remote access.
what should I do?

Comment: You have to host the app: if you don't want it to be in your client's machine, it should be somewhere "distant" [remote]: you have no third option. What's the problem with hosting?

Comment: I don't understand the title of this post.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/) to encode your sources before passing them on to your client.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your client the trouble of setting up a server by hosting the app yourself and using `.htaccess` to password protect the app and/or set up an IP restriction.